# Text box has padding on left side but not right side

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I'm not sure why my text box has padding on the left side but not the right side.
When I look at the text frame options, there's no inset spacing on the left side. I want the padding to be symmetrical. I can make it look symmetrical by adding some padding on the right, but I want to know why this is happening so I can make sure the amount of padding pixels is equal.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your paragraph settings. You might have applied *Left Indent*:

[image]

(It could also be cause by an object we can't see with *Text Wrap* applied.)